# Can Firebase output static content?

Tags: firebase

If I had a blog app on Firebase...

When publishing a blog post, can I get the resulting URL to be cached via the webhosting/CDN feature of Firebase?

Or is the webhosting feature strictly for static content that you manually upload?

Or maybe I can skip the webhosting feature altogether, and have some blog url (eg: blog.com/posts/something) be cached in the CDN as a static html.

Or is Firebase always about JS apps (or apps in general) requesting data and displaying that data must always be a real-time rendering?  Rather than a flat html static/cached version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is the webhosting feature strictly for static content that you manually upload?

Yes, Firebase hosting is meant for hosting static files that you create during your development process. It is not meant as a place to store generated files.